Blender 4.2 in the Extensions tab, my Addons are not showing Addons in 4.2 Beta
in the Extensions tab in Preferences, I see this message "Checking for Extensions updates" Blender hangs and nothing updates the Extensions window.

I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished, under development or experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. These transitory questions are unlikely to be useful in the future, rendering their long term value low, and making them unappealing for a knowledge database site.
